# If $f$ non-negative and bounded and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f d \lambda < \infty \Rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}}f^{2} d \lambda < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, real-numbers

I am trying to show if $f$ is a non-negative function that is bounded and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f d \lambda < \infty \Rightarrow \int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{2} d \lambda < \infty$

Where d$\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

Attempt:

Write $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f^{2} d \lambda = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f||f| d \lambda$. Since we know $f$ is bounded $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f||f| d \lambda$ is also bounded.

This seems too short to be correct...

Comment: Your "is also bounded" is false, there exists $f$ that is bounded but not square integrable, for instance $f=1$. But if $f \in L^1 \cap L^\infty$ you can dominate $f$ by a constant, the other $f$ is integrable...

Comment: Just a comment that $\implies$ and "then" are not interchangeable. In other words, your "$\implies$" should be a "then" or else you are also assuming that "if $f$ has finite integral, so does $f^2$" and then, there is no conclusion (of course, the lack of conclusion makes one infer that "$\implies$" was in fact a "then").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your claim "since we know $f$ is bounded, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f \| f| d \lambda$ is also bounded", this is false. The simplest counterexample is $f(x) = 1$, in which case $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f \| f| d \lambda$ is unbounded.

The solution to the problem is that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f d \lambda<\infty \Rightarrow f \in L^{1}$. Consequently $\left |f \right| < c$ and $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f^{2} d \lambda \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}}c|f| d \lambda$$ for some constant $c$. The result that $f \in L^{2}$ follows from the hypothesis.